# Need facebook email ID after login

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I have done facebook login on my website, but I am not getting user's email in response array. I found solution here that I can get email by this code:

```
try {
    $email = $your_fb_object->api('/me?fields=email', 'GET');
}
catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    //api call has not been successful, deal with an error, e.g. log it…
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But I still get id in response Array ( [id] => 581241998665448 ) not email. Please guide so I can get email id of facebook use who is login.

Comment: did you authorize the user with the email permission?

Answer (score 0):

When you log the user in, are you asking for the `email` scope?

Try this:

```
$login_url = $your_fb_object->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'email', 'redirect_uri' => 'callback_url' ) );
```